# Apple IOS4 UI Automation: Executing a specific test case inside Javascript test file

Tags: javascript, ios, user-interface, ios4, automation

I'm using the Apple IOS4 UI Automation framework to test some iPhone app controls and I have set up my Javascript file as follows:

```
// some functions
...
function Test_TestCase1() { ... }
function Test_TestCase2() { ... }
function Test_TestCase3() { ... }
function Test_TestCase4() { ... }
etc
```

When I set the target and script file inside Instruments, it executes all 4 test cases. Is there a way to execute just ONE test case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write a controller or master script that calls only the functions that you want to run? That is how I would approach it....  :)